# finding limit to the following series with n addends: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+n}}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+n}}\}$

I can't find a way to begin. Help?

Comment: You could start by doing a little search on this website...see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438637/lim-n-to-infty-frac1-sqrtn-left-frac1-sqrtn1-dotso-frac).

Comment: The $n$th term of the series is bounded below by $n\over\sqrt{ 2n}$.

Comment: So it's bounded below by $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}}$, which approaches infinity. But the answer is 0?

Comment: @eontorch Do you really know what "bounded below" means?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yeah, sorry about that. I now realize that the bounder M has to be a real number. But if it's like David said, what does it mean about the limit?

Comment: What does it mean, really? The limit can't be 1, because at some point $\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt2}$ exceeds 1. Can it be 2? Can it be 3?

Comment: It approaches infinity as n does, I've already said it. So by saying that the nth term approaches infinity you can determine that the whole series does too?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+n}} \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+i}}
$$

Now, factoring $n$ out of the square root we have:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+i}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n}}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(  \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n}}} \right)
$$
Now, taking the limit of the factors we have:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n}}}
$$
But since
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow \infty
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n}}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} = 1
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n}}} = \infty
$$
Thus, 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n}}} = \infty
$$
and finally:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+n}} \right) = \infty
$$